# SnakeYaml dump function writes with single quotes

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

Consider the following code:

```
public void testDumpWriter() {
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("NAME1", "Raj");
data.put("NAME2", "Kumar");

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/path/to/file.yaml");
for (Map.Entry m : data.entrySet()) {
            String temp = new StringBuilder().append(m.getKey()).append(": ").append(m.getValue()).toString();
            yaml.dump(temp, file);
        }
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
'NAME1: Raj'
'NAME2: Kumar'
```

But i want the output without the single quotes like

```
NAME1: Raj
NAME2: Kumar
```

This thing is very comfortable for parsing the file.
If anyone have solution, please help me to fix. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well SnakeYaml does exactly what you tell it to: For each entry in the Map, it dumps the concatenation of the key, the String `": "`, and the value as YAML document. A String maps to a Scalar in YAML, and since the scalar contains a `:` followed by space, it must be quoted (else it would be a key-value pair).

What you *actually* want to do is to dump the Map as YAML mapping. You can do it like this:

```
public void testDumpWriter() {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("NAME1", "Raj");
    data.put("NAME2", "Kumar");

    DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
    options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/path/to/file.yaml");
    yaml.dump(data, writer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already tried your code, it prints in csv format *{NAME1: Raj, NAME2: Kumar}*. Actual yml format is mention in my question, and that format is comfortable to parse. And if we dump too many maps, its violate yml format. Would you please help for actual yml format.

Comment: This is definitely not *csv* format, that's something completely different. It is valid YAML, only in flow style (which was designed to resemble JSON). I updated the code to enforce block style, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, its big help for my problem.