# Parsing YAML with arrays of different types

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I am trying to read a YAML file and store the result in a list of POJOs.

I cannot modify the YAML file. I use Jackson 2.10.0 but I am open to any other version. I am trying to parse the following script with Jackson:

## vehicles-notype.yaml

Vehicles is basically a list of objects with some common properties and some unique to the type of vehicle.

```
---
vehicles:
- car:
  make: "Mercedes-Benz"
  model: "S500"
  topSpeed: 250.0
  seatingCapacity: 5
- truck:
  make: "Isuzu"
  model: "NQR"
  payloadCapacity: 7500.0
```

## Desired outpout

After reading the file, I'd like that, if I introspect the list, I'd like to get:

```
... App.java:48): -> start()
... App.java:56): class net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_pojos.Car
... App.java:56): class net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_pojos.Truck
```

The `Car` and `Truck` POJOs are pretty obvious:

## Car

```
package net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_pojos;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Car extends Vehicle {

  private int seatingCapacity;
  private double topSpeed;

  @JsonCreator
  public Car(
      @JsonProperty("make") String make,
      @JsonProperty("model") String model,
      @JsonProperty("seating") int seatingCapacity,
      @JsonProperty("topSpeed") double topSpeed) {
    super(make, model);
    this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
    this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
  }

  public int getSeatingCapacity() {
    return seatingCapacity;
  }

  public void setSeatingCapacity(int seatingCapacity) {
    this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
  }

  public double getTopSpeed() {
    return topSpeed;
  }

  public void setTopSpeed(double topSpeed) {
    this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return "car";
  }

}
```

## Truck

```
package net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_pojos;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Truck extends Vehicle {

  private double payloadCapacity;

  @JsonCreator
  public Truck(
    @JsonProperty("make") String make, 
    @JsonProperty("model") String model, 
    @JsonProperty("payload") double payloadCapacity) {
      super(make, model);
      this.payloadCapacity = payloadCapacity;
  }

  public double getPayloadCapacity() {
    return payloadCapacity;
  }

  public void setPayloadCapacity(double payloadCapacity) {
    this.payloadCapacity = payloadCapacity;
  }

  @Override
  public String getType() {
    return "truck";
  }

}
```

## Fleet

The `Fleet` POJO is also obvious.

```
package net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_pojos;

import java.util.List;

public class Fleet {

  private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

  public void setVehicles(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
    this.vehicles= vehicles;
  }

  public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
    return vehicles;
  }

}
```

## Vehicle

`Vehicle` is a bit more tricky, as I am trying to play with `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`. You can see the commented code, which is slowly driving me mad:

```
package net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_pojos;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY
//    ,
//    property = "className"
    )

@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value = Car.class, name = "car"),
  @Type(value = Truck.class, name = "truck")
})

//@JsonSubTypes({
//    @Type(value = Car.class, name = "car"),
//    @Type(value = Truck.class, name = "truck")
//})
public abstract class Vehicle {
  private String make;
  private String model;

  @JsonProperty("type")
  abstract public String getType();

  public void setType(String type) {};

  protected Vehicle(String make, String model) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
  }

  public String getMake() {
    return make;
  }

  public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
  }

  public String getModel() {
    return model;
  }

  public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
  }
}
```

## App

Finally the application code, which is pretty obvious too.

```
package net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_read_diff_objects;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

import net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_pojos.Fleet;
import net.jgp.labs.jackson.yaml.lab411_pojos.Vehicle;

/**
 * What does it do?
 * 
 * @author jgp
 */
public class ReadListVehicleNoTypeApp {
  private static final Logger log =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadListVehicleNoTypeApp.class);

  /**
   * main() is your entry point to the application.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadListVehicleNoTypeApp app = new ReadListVehicleNoTypeApp();
    try {
      app.start();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * The processing code.
   * 
   * @throws IOException
   */
  protected boolean start() throws IOException {
    log.debug("-> start()");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    Fleet fleet = mapper.readValue(new File("data/vehicles-notype.yaml"),
        Fleet.class);
    for (Vehicle v : fleet.getVehicles()) {
      log.debug("{}", v.getClass());
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure there is something to play with the @Json family of attributes, but I am slowly losing it ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`car` and `truck` are a field names, properties. I am not aware about `Jackson` annotation which allows to set types from different fields.

If `Yaml` file can not be modified, we can use `Streaming API` to read type property and deserialise `Vehicle`. In pseudocode it could look like:

```
while token != EOF
    while token != FIELD_NAME
        nextToken()

    fieldName = nextFieldName();
    clazz = convertToClass(fieldName);
    vehicles.add(read(clazz));
```

Luckily, field name which defines type is a first field name and we can read it manually and use `Jackson` to read type after that. I removed `JsonSubTypes` and `JsonTypeInfo` annotation from `Vehicle` class and with `Streaming API` it could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class YamlApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File yamlFile = new File("./resource/test.yaml").getAbsoluteFile();

        FleetDeserializer deserializer = new FleetDeserializer();
        Fleet fleet = deserializer.readValue(yamlFile);

        System.out.println(fleet);
    }
}

class FleetDeserializer {
    private YAMLFactory factory = new YAMLFactory();
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);

    public Fleet readValue(File yamlFile) throws IOException {
        Fleet fleet = new Fleet();
        fleet.setVehicles(new ArrayList<>());

        YAMLParser parser = factory.createParser(yamlFile);
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                continue;
            }
            // skip everything until a field name
            while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) ;

            Class<? extends Vehicle> type = getType(parser.getCurrentName());
            if (type == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // skip field name
            parser.nextToken();
            parser.nextToken();

            // read next vehicle
            fleet.getVehicles().add(mapper.readValue(parser, type));
        }

        return fleet;
    }

    private Class<? extends Vehicle> getType(String fieldName) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(fieldName);
        switch (fieldName) {
            case "car":
                return Car.class;
            case "truck":
                return Truck.class;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Fleet{vehicles=[Car{seatingCapacity=5, topSpeed=250.0, make='Mercedes-Benz', model='S500'}, Truck{payloadCapacity=7500.0, make='Isuzu', model='NQR'}]}
```

Comment: This is great Micha... However, when I do that:
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    String jsonDataString = mapper.writeValueAsString(fleet);
Then it loses the type. Do you think I will need a custom serializer?

Comment: @jgp, since we removed all annotation related to type info we need to write custom serialiser or in each class provide extra field/getter: `getCar(){return "";}` in `Car` class and `getTruck(){return "";}` in `Truck` class. And if needed annotate class with `@JsonPropertyOrder` to be sure that type will be the first field.

Comment: Brilliant :)... I still get something like: - car: ""
  make: "Mercedes-Benz"
Any chance I could get rid of the double quotes? I tried with include/null values, but no luck...

Comment: @jgp it is not an easy task to do that since behind the scene `SnakeYAML` is used and you should configure it somehow to not writing quotes for empty string. Moreover it is not a bug it is a feature: [(yaml) Empty string serialized without quotes if MINIMIZE_QUOTES is enabled](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/50). See [SnakeYaml dump function writes with single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913105/snakeyaml-dump-function-writes-with-single-quotes) and [8.1.2. Literal Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/block/literal) in documentation.

Comment: @jgp, there is a dirty hack I found but I am not sure it will work for you since we disable quotes for all `String` values. You need to enable `YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES` feature. For example: `factory.enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES);` and instead empty string you need to return [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space): `public String getCar() {return "\u00A0";}` or `public char getTruck() {return 0X00A0;}` . Now, this char should not be visible in output and quotes should be removed. Drawback: quotes are removed everywhere.